# More Efficient Way to Organize Custom Wordpress Posts by State

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance

Okay, so I'm using the Types plugin and Posts 2 Posts plugins to build a site that has a custom post type called 'opening' that holds information about a specific job opening and its associated consultant(s). I need to be able to display these posts on a page, organized by state (Alabama, Alaska, etc). I have a solution but it seems very inefficient.

I wouldn't worry about it too much but it's being hosted on a server with very limited resources and my solution, while it works great on my development server, times out on the live server.

Here's the code I'm using for each state:

```
    <!-- -----------------------Alabama ------------------------ -->

<!-- Pulls the list of openings -->
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'current-opening', 'meta_key' => 'wpcf-state', 'meta_value' => 'alabama', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>  

<a name="alabama">
<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
       <?php $cat = types_render_field( "state" );
       if( $cat == 'Alabama' ) : ?>
            <?php if( $count == 1 ){ echo "<h2>Alabama</h2>"; ++$count; ++$alabama; echo "<hr />"; } ?>

        <ul>
        <li><h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title( ); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo(types_render_field( "position", array("show_name" => "true") )); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo(types_render_field( "enrollment", array( "show_name" => "true" ) )); ?></li>

        <!-- Display the connected Consultant(s) -->
        <?php
        // Find connected Consultants
        $connected = new WP_Query( array(
        'connected_type' => 'consultant_to_opening',
        'connected_items' => $post,
        'nopaging' => true
        ) );

        // Display connected Consultants
        p2p_list_posts( $connected, array(
            'before_list' => '<li>Consultant(s): ',
            'separator' => ', ',
            'after_list'  => '</li>',
        ) );
        ?>

        <li><?php echo(types_render_field( "school-district-website", array( "show_name" => "true", "no_protocol" => "true" ) )); ?></li>

        <?php $deadline = types_render_field( "application-deadline", array( "show_name" => "true", "style" => "text" ) );
        if( $deadline ) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $deadline; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $app_word = types_render_field( "application-form-word", array( "show_name" => "true", "link" => "true", "title" => "Download" ) );
        if( $app_word ) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $app_word; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $app_pdf = types_render_field( "application-form-pdf", array( "show_name" => "true", "link" => "true", "title" => "Download" ) );
        if ( $app_pdf ) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $app_pdf; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $app_link = types_render_field( "application-link", array( "show_name" => "true", "link" => "true", "title" => "Click Here" ) );
        if ( $app_link ) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $app_link; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $vacancy = types_render_field( "announcement-of-vacancy", array( "show_name" => "true", "link" => "true", "title" => "Download" ) );
        if( $vacancy ) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $vacancy; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $notes = types_render_field( "notes", array( "show_name" => "true" ) );
        if ( $notes ) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $notes; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
       <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- -----------------------/Alabama ------------------------ -->
```

The problem here is that I'm querying the database to get the openings associated with that state and then looping through each result to display each of its fields and then querying the database for its associated consultant(s). It's not a lot of work if I were just doing this for 1 state but I have to do it for all 50 states plus Washington DC and display it all on one page.

Is there anything I can do to make this more efficient?

Comment: have you considered writing a custom query to do this instead of relying on WordPress functions?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the `types_render_field()` function isn't very efficient. I helped myself quite a bit by replacing those functions with the built-in Wordpress function for displaying custom fields: `get_post_meta()`